# Bootstrap datepicker daysOfWeekDisabled not working

Tags: jquery, calendar, bootstrap-datepicker

```
<input class="form-control0" data-provide="datepicker" name="order_delivery_date" id="order_delivery_date"  required />
```

underneath it I am doing:

```
<script>
$('#order_delivery_date').datepicker({
   daysOfWeekDisabled: "0,6"
}); 
</script>
```

But the calendar appears without any days disabled (Saturday and Sunday are shown as valid selections).

Possible clue: without the

data-provide="datepicker"

the datepicker calendar does not appear.

jQuery 1.11, Bootstrap 3.2.0.

Comment: The days need to be provided in an array format. daysOfWeekDisabled: [0,6]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is working pretty fine for me. Maybe it is just problem of including the right js and css. Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Academia/yskvvsvp/) to see a working example.

The following links are the one used in the demo:

**Imported css:**

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Imported js:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  It's something in my setup that's messing me up.  Does the fact that datepicker doesn't work unless I use data-provide="datepicker" indicate what's wrong?  Or is that a red herring.

Comment: I think I am somehow colliding with another datepicker in this program.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem.  I had to change my inclusions when I was doing this.  Thanks for confirming that I wasn't crazy!  For others in this situation - don't include mootools for desktop calendars if you are doing this too- determine which one is required and only include one.

Comment: @ScottWilson sorry for the late reply. Happy that you find a solution :)